# Android: multitouch max fingers for a 2 fingers max device : Returns 5 fingers max

Tags: java, android, multi-touch, smartphone, touchscreen

I would like to check how many fingers on the screen the android device can detect.
I'm using this script:

```
getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH);
getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_DISTINCT;
getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_JAZZHAND;
```

It always returns TRUE FOR ALL on my 2 Androids devices.
BUT they can detect only 2 fingers at the same time on the screen maximum.

Is there another method to check that?

Comment: "BUT they can detect only 2 fingers at the same time on the screen maximum" -- how have you determined this? What devices are these?

Comment: I just put all my fingers on the screen with test apps like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.the511plus.MultiTouchTester I also coded my own app with Unity.

Comment: I got Wiko Ozzy on OS 4.2.2 Kitkat and Motorola Droid X on OS 4.4.4. I also compared with my other devices on 4.4.2 and 6.0